# Which key and certificate from keystore and truststore is used when there are many?

Tags: java, ssl

I have two keys in my keystore:

```
D:\javasslstores2>keytool -list -keystore keystore.jks -storepass passwd123

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

ssl_key_2, Jun 14, 2018, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 36:A4:FB:E6:47:12:59:D6:C3:E1:06:21:4B:21:79:7E:33:86:48:52
ssl_key, Jun 13, 2018, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 03:08:2C:CA:A4:84:DD:61:20:05:F7:56:F5:44:4C:A4:35:2B:8C:6C
```

and corresponding two certificates in my trustore:

```
D:\javasslstores2>keytool -list -keystore truststore.jks -storepass passwd123

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

ssl_key_2, Jun 14, 2018, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 36:A4:FB:E6:47:12:59:D6:C3:E1:06:21:4B:21:79:7E:33:86:48:52
ssl_key, Jun 14, 2018, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 03:08:2C:CA:A4:84:DD:61:20:05:F7:56:F5:44:4C:A4:35:2B:8C:6C
```

I have written simple java ssl client and servers:

**Server**

```
public class Server {
    static KeyStore ks;
    static KeyManagerFactory kmf;
    static TrustManagerFactory tmf;
    static SSLContext sc;
    static TrustManager[] trustManagers;

    static {
        try {
            ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            ks.load(new FileInputStream("D:\\javasslstores\\keystore.jks"), "passwd123".toCharArray());

            kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            kmf.init(ks, "passwd123".toCharArray());

            tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509"); 
            tmf.init(ks);

            sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); 
            sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("SSL Server");
        SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = sc.getServerSocketFactory(); 
        SSLServerSocket s = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(8089);
        System.out.println("Listening on port 8089");
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) s.accept();


        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))) {
            String line;
            System.out.println("Data from client:");
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
                out.println(line);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Closed");
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
public class Client {
    static KeyStore ks;
    static KeyManagerFactory kmf;
    static TrustManagerFactory tmf;
    static SSLContext sc;
    static TrustManager[] trustManagers;

    static 
    {
        try 
        {
            ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            ks.load(new FileInputStream("D:\\javasslstores\\keystore.jks"), "passwd123".toCharArray());

            kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            kmf.init(ks, "passwd123".toCharArray());

            tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509"); 
            tmf.init(ks);

            sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); 
            sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SSLSocketFactory ssf = sc.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) ssf.createSocket("localhost", 8089);
        socket.startHandshake();

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter
                                (new BufferedWriter
                                (new OutputStreamWriter
                                (socket.getOutputStream())));

        System.out.println("SSL Client");

        out.println("GET / HTTP/1.0");
        out.println("From java ssl client");
        out.println("written by me");
        out.flush();

        if (out.checkError())
            System.out.println("SSLSocketClient:  java.io.PrintWriter error");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                socket.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);

        in.close();
        out.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Above code runs fine.

**Doubts:**

1. There are two keys and certificates with name `ssl_key` and `ssl_key_2`. Which one they use?
2. How they end up using same pair of key and certificate?

Comment: That server code doesn't request client auth, so the client even though you gave it the keystore should not use any key (and cert) for itself at all; it should only verify the server's cert using the truststore. PS: that's not a valid HTTP request, but then your server isn't an HTTP server either.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. The implementation of *SunX509* KeyManager (`SunX509KeyManagerImpl`) uses  the first aliases it finds for which there is a private key and a key of type **RSA**.
You can debug the `SunX509KeyManagerImpl.chooseServerAlias` called by your **Server** class on `main` method, in order to verify the logic.
To change the behaviour of the `SunX509KeyManager` you could write your own keyManager extending `X509ExtendedKeyManager` and passing it to `SSLContext.init`.

Comment: Actually it returns the first privatekey entry if any with type matching a mutually-acceptable ciphersuite in preference order -- and since the client here is Java, the most preferred ciphersuites will default to ECDSA then RSA then DSA. The code actually checks the type of the publickey in the cert, not the privatekey, but normally keytool forces those to be the same, and if some other program makes them different the handshake fails; and it appears to also check the cert's parent for EC -- I think in more cases than the RFCs specify -- but I can't easily test. ...

Comment: ... Anyway concur you can write your own KM, or sometimes easier you can adjust the contents of the keystore after loading and before passing it to KMF.

Comment: I was guessing which line in the class `SunX509KeyManagerImpl` results in this behavior. Is it [this](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java#L263) and [this](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java#L271) lines. Or some other lines?