# Unable to perform communication between java client and python server with SSL

Tags: java, python, ssl

I am trying to use keys and certificate generated using java `keytool` in python server and java client. I have created key & keystore, exported certificate, added certificate to truststore, converted keystore to standard pkcs format and then extracted key and certificate from pkcs to use in python server. (first three steps from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablrb/index.html) and last three steps from [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/66865/89945)) Here are the detailed steps:

1. Creating keystore, private key and certificate

   ```
   keytool -genkey -alias ssl_key -keyalg RSA -keypass passwd123 -keystore keystore.jks -storepass passwd123
   ```
2. Exporting certificate out from keystore to `.cer` file

   ```
   keytool -export -alias ssl_key -file ssl_key.cer -keystore keystore.jks -storepass passwd123
   ```
3. Exporting certificate from keystore to truststore

   ```
   keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias ssl_key -keypass passwd123 -file ssl_key.cer -keystore truststore.jks -storepass passwd123
   ```
4. Exported keystore from keytool's proprietary format to standard format

   ```
   keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -destkeystore stdkeystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -srcalias ssl_key -deststorepass passwd123 -destkeypass passwd123
   ```
5. Exported certificate from standard format keystore using openssl

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -in stdkeystore.p12 -nokeys -out cert.pem
   ```
6. Exported unencrypted private key from standard format keystore using openssl as follows:

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -in stdkeystore.p12  -nodes -nocerts -out key.pem
   ```

My small python server and java client are as follows:

**server.py**

```
import socket
import ssl

def start_server_ssl():

    socketObj = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 6000)
    socketObj.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    socketObj.bind(server_address)
    socketObj.listen(10)

    while True:
        try:
            print("Awaiting connection...")
            data_socket, client_address = socketObj.accept()
            ssl_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(socketObj,
                            server_side = True,
                            certfile="cert.pem",
                            keyfile="key.pem")        

            reading_status = True
            data = bytearray()
            data_decoded = ""
            while(reading_status):
                message_chunks = data_socket.recv(90000)
                data.extend(message_chunks)

                print(data)          
                data_decoded = str(data.decode("utf-8"))
                #data_decoded = str(data.decode())

                if(data_decoded.startswith("<<startMessage>>")):
                    if(data_decoded.endswith("<<endMessage>>")):
                        reading_status = False
                        print(data_decoded);

        except socket.error as msg:
            print (msg)

    ssl_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    ssl_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server_ssl()
```

**Client4Py.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.KeyStore;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

public class Client4Py {
    static KeyStore ks;
    static KeyManagerFactory kmf;
    static TrustManagerFactory tmf;
    static SSLContext sc;
    static TrustManager[] trustManagers;

    static {
        try {
            ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            ks.load(new FileInputStream("D:\\javasslstores\\truststore.jks"), "passwd123".toCharArray());

            kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            kmf.init(ks, "passwd123".toCharArray());

            tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509"); 
            tmf.init(ks);

            sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); 

            sc.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SSLSocketFactory ssf = sc.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) ssf.createSocket("127.0.0.1", 6000);
        socket.startHandshake();

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())));

        out.println("<<startMessage>>");
        out.println("Message from Client4Py");
        out.println("<<endMessage>>");
        out.flush();

        if (out.checkError())
            System.out.println(
                "SSLSocketClient:  java.io.PrintWriter error");

        out.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

The output on server's console after first running server and the client is as follows:

```
Awaiting connection...
bytearray(b'\x16\x03\x03\x00\xc1\x01\x00\x00\xbd\x03\x03["}o\x12\x01\xb2\xd4E\xa1\x1fy\xa8/d\x11\xd2\x00)\\t\x9a:\xb6\n\xcd\x03\x05\xbe\xe58\xd6\x00\x00:\xc0#\xc0\'\x00<\xc0%\xc0)\x00g\x00@\xc0\t\xc0\x13\x00/\xc0\x04\xc0\x0e\x003\x002\xc0+\xc0/\x00\x9c\xc0-\xc01\x00\x9e\x00\xa2\xc0\x08\xc0\x12\x00\n\xc0\x03\xc0\r\x00\x16\x00\x13\x00\xff\x01\x00\x00Z\x00\n\x004\x002\x00\x17\x00\x01\x00\x03\x00\x13\x00\x15\x00\x06\x00\x07\x00\t\x00\n\x00\x18\x00\x0b\x00\x0c\x00\x19\x00\r\x00\x0e\x00\x0f\x00\x10\x00\x11\x00\x02\x00\x12\x00\x04\x00\x05\x00\x14\x00\x08\x00\x16\x00\x0b\x00\x02\x01\x00\x00\r\x00\x18\x00\x16\x06\x03\x06\x01\x05\x03\x05\x01\x04\x03\x04\x01\x03\x03\x03\x01\x02\x03\x02\x01\x02\x02')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Mahesh\workspaces\workspace6\PythonServer\server.py", line 44, in <module>
    start_server_ssl()
  File "D:\Mahesh\workspaces\workspace6\PythonServer\server.py", line 29, in start_server_ssl
    data_decoded = str(data.decode("utf-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 4: invalid start byte
```

I uncommented utf-8 encoding-decoding lines in client and server code and ended up getting following output on server's console:

```
Awaiting connection...
bytearray(b'\x16\x03\x03\x00\xc1\x01\x00\x00\xbd\x03\x03["\x7f>s\x04\x15S\x14\xb0\xa2\xa0\x7f\x90}@\xe8\xa3:\x15\x04z\xeb\x986\\b\xe9\xe0v=\x1f\x00\x00:\xc0#\xc0\'\x00<\xc0%\xc0)\x00g\x00@\xc0\t\xc0\x13\x00/\xc0\x04\xc0\x0e\x003\x002\xc0+\xc0/\x00\x9c\xc0-\xc01\x00\x9e\x00\xa2\xc0\x08\xc0\x12\x00\n\xc0\x03\xc0\r\x00\x16\x00\x13\x00\xff\x01\x00\x00Z\x00\n\x004\x002\x00\x17\x00\x01\x00\x03\x00\x13\x00\x15\x00\x06\x00\x07\x00\t\x00\n\x00\x18\x00\x0b\x00\x0c\x00\x19\x00\r\x00\x0e\x00\x0f\x00\x10\x00\x11\x00\x02\x00\x12\x00\x04\x00\x05\x00\x14\x00\x08\x00\x16\x00\x0b\x00\x02\x01\x00\x00\r\x00\x18\x00\x16\x06\x03\x06\x01\x05\x03\x05\x01\x04\x03\x04\x01\x03\x03\x03\x01\x02\x03\x02\x01\x02\x02')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Mahesh\workspaces\workspace6\PythonServer\server.py", line 44, in <module>
    start_server_ssl()
  File "D:\Mahesh\workspaces\workspace6\PythonServer\server.py", line 30, in start_server_ssl
    data_decoded = str(data.decode())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 4: invalid start byte
```

I feel I am missing something. Either some basics of SSL or encoding. Can I use pem file generated from java keystore as explained above directly with python `SSLSocket`? Or do I have to ensure something more like ciphers used to generate keys and certificate?

Any links/resources to dispel my ignorance are welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced your `server.py` with this example. There is nothing wrong with your server about keys and certificates.

**server.py**

```
import socket
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SO_REUSEADDR, SOL_SOCKET, SHUT_RDWR
import ssl

KEYFILE = 'key.pem'
CERTFILE = 'cert.pem'

def print_data(s):
    while True:
        data = s.recv(8192)
        print(data.decode("utf-8"))
        if data == b'':
            break
        s.send(b'This is a response.')
        print('Connection closed')
    s.close()

def start_server_ssl(address):
    s = socket.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(address)
    s.listen(1)
    s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    ssl_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(s, keyfile=KEYFILE, certfile=CERTFILE, server_side=True)
    print("Awaiting connection...") 

    while True:
        try:
            (c,a) = ssl_socket.accept()
            print('Got connection', c, a)
            print_data(c)
        except socket.error as e:
            print('Error: {0}'.format(e))

start_server_ssl((socket.gethostbyname('localhost'), 6000))
```

Comment: did you tried both client and server and did it work for you?

Comment: Yes I user your Java client

Comment: I see three differences: **(1)** you used two `while`s, one for accepting different connections and another for receiving all data. (my original code forked new process per connection, thats why simplified code in question contained single `while`). **(2)** you followed sequence: `s.bind`, `s.listen`, `s.setsocketopt`, I followed `s.sersocketopt`, `s.bind`, `s.listen`. **(3)** You followed sequnce: `ssl.wrap_socket()`,`ssl_socket.accept()`, I followed: `socketObj.accept`,`ssl.wrap_socket()`. What might have broken my code? And why? Will help to better understand SSL and socket programming.

Comment: That worked, but still I have doubts asked in above comment. Also can you please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50858234/which-key-and-certificate-from-keystore-and-truststore-is-used-when-there-are-ma) question?