# Creating new process for each request on SSL socket gives "TypeError: Cannot serialize socket object", but doing same with normal/non SSL socket works

Tags: java, python, sockets, ssl

I am trying to use keys and certificate generated using java `keytool` in python server and java client. I have created key & keystore, exported certificate, added certificate to truststore, converted keystore to standard pkcs format and then extracted key and certificate from pkcs to use in python server. (first three steps from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablrb/index.html) and last three steps from [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/66865/89945)). This question is somewhat follow up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860354/unable-to-perform-communication-between-java-client-and-python-server-with-ssl/50861563#50861563) and detailed steps for generating key and certificate can be found in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860354/unable-to-perform-communication-between-java-client-and-python-server-with-ssl/50861563#50861563).

My SSL server looks like this

**server.py**

```
import socket
import multiprocessing as mup
import ssl

def worker_ssl(data_socket, client_address):
    print("Inside worker")
    #some processing

def start_server_ssl():

    socketObj = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = ("127.0.0.1", 6000)
    socketObj.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    socketObj.bind(server_address)
    socketObj.listen(10)

    ssl_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(socketObj,
                            server_side = True,
                            certfile="cert.pem",
                            keyfile="key.pem")        

    while True:
        print("Waiting For Connections .........\n")
        try:
            data_socket, client_address = ssl_socket.accept()

            process = mup.Process(target=worker_ssl, args=(data_socket, client_address))            
            process.daemon = True
            process.start()

        except socket.error as msg:
            print (" [ERROR] : %s " % msg)
            continue

    socketObj.close()
    ssl_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    ssl_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server_ssl()
```

SSL Client looks like this:

**Client4Py.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.KeyStore;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

public class Client4Py {
    static KeyStore ks;
    static KeyManagerFactory kmf;
    static TrustManagerFactory tmf;
    static SSLContext sc;
    static TrustManager[] trustManagers;

    static {
        try {
            ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            ks.load(new FileInputStream("D:\\javasslstores\\truststore.jks"), "passwd123".toCharArray());

            kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            kmf.init(ks, "passwd123".toCharArray());

            tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509"); 
            tmf.init(ks);

            sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); 

            sc.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SSLSocketFactory ssf = sc.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) ssf.createSocket("127.0.0.1", 6000);
        socket.startHandshake();

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())));

        out.println("<<startMessage>>");
        out.println("Message from Client4Py");
        out.println("<<endMessage>>");
        out.flush();

        if (out.checkError())
            System.out.println(
                "SSLSocketClient:  java.io.PrintWriter error");

        out.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

The output on server's console after first running server and then the client is as follows:

```
1    Waiting For Connections .........
2    
3    Traceback (most recent call last):
4      File "D:\workspaces\workspace6\PythonServer\server.py", line 40, in <module>
5        start_server_ssl()
6      File "D:\workspaces\workspace6\PythonServer\server.py", line 29, in start_server_ssl
7        process.start()
8      File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
9        self._popen = self._Popen(self)
10      File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
11        return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
12      File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
13        return Popen(process_obj)
14      File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
15        reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
16      File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
17        ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
18      File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\socket.py", line 185, in __getstate__
19        raise TypeError("Cannot serialize socket object")
20    TypeError: Cannot serialize socket object
21    Traceback (most recent call last):
22      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
23      File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
24        new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
25      File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
26        _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
27    PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

You can see on line 20, there is `TypeError: Cannot serialize socket object`.

**Code starts working after removing all SSL stuffs**

When I comment call to `wrap_socket()`, replace `ssl_socket.accept()` with `socketObject.accept()` and comment `ssl_socket.shutdown()` and `close()`, the code starts working. It creates new process from `worker()` as desired and ends printing `Inside worker` on console. Here is the modified non SSL server:

```
import socket
import multiprocessing as mup
# import ssl

def worker_ssl(data_socket, client_address):
    print("Inside worker")
    #some processing

def start_server_ssl():

    socketObj = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = ("127.0.0.1", 6000)
    socketObj.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    socketObj.bind(server_address)
    socketObj.listen(10)

#     ssl_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(socketObj,
#                             server_side = True,
#                             certfile="cert.pem",
#                             keyfile="key.pem")        

    while True:
        print("Waiting For Connections .........\n")
        try:
            data_socket, client_address = socketObj.accept()

            process = mup.Process(target=worker_ssl, args=(data_socket, client_address))            
            process.daemon = True
            process.start()

        except socket.error as msg:
            print (" [ERROR] : %s " % msg)
            continue

    socketObj.close()
#     ssl_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
#     ssl_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server_ssl()
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this problem by accept the socket in the clear wrapping it with SSLContext within the child process. Everything I needed to create the SSLContext multiprocessing had no issues serializing.

UPDATE: The following is a server sudo code which illustrates the explanation above:

```
def client_connection_handler(client_socket, client_address, ssl_settings):
    context = ssl.SSLContext()
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile=ssl_settings['certfile'], keyfile=ssl_settings['keyfile'],)
    context.verify_mode = ssl_settings["verify_mode"]
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile=ssl_settings["cafile"])
    client_secured_socket = context.wrap_socket(client_socket, server_side=True)
    #
    # send and receive data
    #
    client_secured_socket.close()


def server():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((hostname, port))
    server_socket.listen(5)
    while True:
        # Waiting for client connection
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        concurrent_connections = len(multiprocessing.active_children())
        if max_concurrent_clients > concurrent_connections:
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=client_connection_handler, args=(client_socket, client_address, ssl_settings))
            p.daemon = True
            p.start()
            continue
        # Max client connection has been reached
        client_socket.close()
```

Comment: Please provide the answer rather than just an explination https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether I understood the exact reason, but I am stating it here.

Looking at following stacktrace lines:

```
17        ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
18      File "D:\Programs\python\python-3.6.6-amd64\lib\socket.py", line 185, in __getstate__
19        raise TypeError("Cannot serialize socket object")
20    TypeError: Cannot serialize socket object
```

it seems that `multiprocessing` module's [`Process.start()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.Process.start) method serializes the parameters passed to it for passing them to new process. And it further seems that [`SSLSocket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl-sockets) objects cannot be serialized. However, it seems that [`Socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-objects) objects can be serialized. [This issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue30829) states the same and thats why the `Socket` based server works. However, I dont get why is this so (`SSLSocket` is not serializable but `Socket` objects can be serialized). I mean is there any method that is implemented by `Socket` objects which are not implemented by `SSLSocket`. Also note that the error occurs at [`socket.py, line 185, in __getstate__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/socket.py#L191), that is in `Socket` class, but not in `SSLSocket` class.

***I will like if someone confirms above reason (that is `SSLSocket` objects are not serializable and `Socket` objects are serializable), explains exactly why  is this the case and provides solution for using `SSLSocket` with `multiprocessing` module.***

**Workaround**

I ended up forking new process using [`os.fork`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fork). (Examples of `os.fork` can be found [here](https://www.python-course.eu/forking.php)). Its supported on linux only. So, I [installed python on cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50950390/1317018) and then used it.