# Unable to install python package with pip, getting Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install [pyjks](https://pypi.org/project/pyjks/).
Am running everything in admin command prompt.
Initial try to install pyjks resulted in this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pyjks
Collecting pyjks
Collecting pycryptodome (from pyjks)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/82/bd/bd192c1314bde108a91295fbec02bc20a816330feb10273aa36d885004ab/pycryptodome-3.6.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting pyasn1-modules (from pyjks)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/51/bcd96bf6231d4b2cc5e023c511bee86637ba375c44a6f9d1b4b7ad1ce4b9/pyasn1_modules-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1 (from pyjks)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a0/70/2c27740f08e477499ce19eefe05dbcae6f19fdc49e9e82ce4768be0643b9/pyasn1-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting twofish (from pyjks)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/82/b4/9eb026a8e62a04512435d3de25c93f7bda51c8b8c7991c1c0be70b5115a6/twofish-0.3.0.tar.gz
Collecting javaobj-py3 (from pyjks)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/7d/1979d67bb8f6c5babb8dda0cb79d6d4663ef9a039c193b5adcc787a86285/javaobj_py3-0.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pycryptodome, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, twofish, javaobj-py3, pyjks
  Running setup.py install for twofish ... error
    Complete output from command "c:\program files\python36\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\crrma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xlk00hde\\twofish\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\crrma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5jn53157\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    copying twofish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    running build_ext
    building '_twofish' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\program files\python36\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\crrma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xlk00hde\\twofish\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\crrma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5jn53157\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\crrma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xlk00hde\twofish\
```

I installed Visual C++ 14.0 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145) and tried reinstalling. But got same error.

So as suggested in several comments on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat), I upgraded setuptools:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install --upgrade setuptools
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/e1/820d941153923aac1d49d7fc37e17b6e73bfbd2904959fffbad77900cf92/setuptools-39.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 39.0.1
    Uninstalling setuptools-39.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-39.0.1
Successfully installed setuptools-39.2.0
```

But still getting the same error. So as suggested on [same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat), I downloaded tar.gz from [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyjks/) and installed from it:

```
C:\Users\crrma\Downloads>pip install pyjks-17.1.1.tar.gz
Processing c:\users\crrma\downloads\pyjks-17.1.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages (from pyjks==17.1.1) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1_modules in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages (from pyjks==17.1.1) (0.2.1)
Collecting javaobj-py3 (from pyjks==17.1.1)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/7d/1979d67bb8f6c5babb8dda0cb79d6d4663ef9a039c193b5adcc787a86285/javaobj_py3-0.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pycryptodome in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages (from pyjks==17.1.1) (3.6.1)
Collecting twofish (from pyjks==17.1.1)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/82/b4/9eb026a8e62a04512435d3de25c93f7bda51c8b8c7991c1c0be70b5115a6/twofish-0.3.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: javaobj-py3, twofish, pyjks
  Running setup.py install for twofish ... error
    Complete output from command "c:\program files\python36\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\crrma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c3n_0udc\\twofish\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\crrma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tpgigq69\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    copying twofish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    running build_ext
    building '_twofish' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\program files\python36\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\crrma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c3n_0udc\\twofish\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\crrma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tpgigq69\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\crrma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c3n_0udc\twofish\
```

But its simply not getting installed. Whats going wrong here?

I am running latest version of python:

```
C:\>python
Python 3.6.6rc1 (v3.6.6rc1:1015e38be4, Jun 12 2018, 08:38:06) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Comment: it looks like the system is trying to compile twofish on your machine - and so needs a C++ compiler. Can you just use the regular "pip install twofish"?

Comment: Getting same error after doing `pip install twofish`. Seems that even after installing VC++ redistributable, its not finding the compiler...right? If yes, how can I fix it?

Comment: The [URL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145) you pointer to provides  Visual C++ *Redistributable* for Visual Studio 2015. It's not a compiler, it's **Redistributable Package** with **run-time components that are required to run C++ applications**. You need to install Visual C++ 14 **compiler**.

Comment: does that means I have to install full VS with C, C++? Is this even intended for installing single package of python?

Comment: Yes, if the package contains C extensions and doesn't provide binary wheels or has such packages as dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to fix this up. (I tried by installing [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145), but it didnt work. It seems that what I installed is runtime but not the compiler and we need to install Visual Studio for installing compiler. I was not feeling great to run big setup of the Visual Studio just to install single python package.) Instead I resorted to setting up cygwin (which is small compared to Visual Studio and was already installed on my machine). I tried running `pip3 install pyjks` on cygwin terminal, but now it gave error saying it did not find gcc. It seems that somehow some dependencies of `pyjks` needs to be compiled by C compiler. So I installed gcc in cygwin. However it was also failing. So I installed gcc using `apt-cyg`. All the steps are explained below.

1. Install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)
2. In cygwin setup, select python3, pip3 and gcc-g++ packages in package selection window:

   - python3-devel: Py3K language interpreter
   - python3-pip: Python package installation tool
   - gcc-core: GNU Compiler Collection (C,OpenMP)
   - gcc-g++: GNU Compiler Collection (C++)

   [image]
3. If you forget to select them or if you have cygwin already installed and want to install these additional packages, then you can rerun the cygwin setup (that is, `path-to-cygwin\cygwin\setup\setup-x86_64.exe`) and select above packages.
4. I was not able to install gcc by above approach. It was giving me following error:
   [image]
   So I tried installing it using `apt-cyg`. You can find steps to install `apt-cyg` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50946609/1317018). Once `apt-cyg` is accessible from `cyg-win` terminal (that is, `path-to-cygwin\cygwin\setup\Cygwin.bat`), you can run following command to install `gcc`

   ```
   apt-cyg install gcc-g++
   ```
5. Once gcc is installed, you can install `pyjks` using `pip` (it will not give any error saying C compiler not found):

   ```
   pip3 install pyjks
   ```

I was even able to point python inside cygwin (that is, `path-to-cygwin\cygwin\bin\python3`) as python interpreter for eclipse PyDev module. This also allowed me to use `os.fork()` in python, since windows python's `os` module does not contain `fork()`.